# Windows 11 Desktop Icon Size Does not go back to normal

Tags: windows-11

After trying out display scaling and font size changes. I reset everything back to what it was, yet the desktop icons did not go back to what they were before.

I tried all possible settings from the options, such as selecting/deselecting icon grid settings, changing the size to large, small and restarting multiple times.
Following screenshot shows the huge gaps within those icons and the big selection box

[image: Screengrab]

Comment: Have you restarted?

Comment: Hold down Ctrl and roll the mouse wheel. That works neatly for me with no other special changes or registry fixes.

Comment: @John: It's not a matter of icon size. It will still have an unusual/bigger space between the icon columns. I had this issue myself.

Comment: On my two Windows 11 machines, rolling the mouse button changes both size and spacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **Registry Editor** (<kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, type `regedit` and press Enter) and go to the following location:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics\

Search for **IconSpacing** and **IconVerticalSpacing** and change the value to -1128.

Exit Registry Editor and sign out, then sign back in. It should solve your issue.

Comment: Amazing, this solved the vertical gap. Any suggestions for the horizontal box size? Big distance between two columns

Comment: Changed the iconspacing , worked like charm. Thanks a ton!